# How can I make this mountain Haskell code work?

Tags: list, haskell

How can I put the 2 list in 1 list, because this code only give me back the fisrt list.

```
mountain :: Int -> [Int]

mountain 0 = [0]
mountain 1 = [0]
mountain 2 = [0,2,0]
mountain 3 = [0,2,0]
mountain x 
    | x `mod` 2 == 0 = [0,2..x] ++ [x-2..0]
    | otherwise = [0,2..x-1] ++ [x-3..0]
```

```
Examples:
--mountain 0 == [0]
--mountain 6 == [0,2,4,6,4,2,0]
--mountain 7 == [0,2,4,6,4,2,0]
--mountain 10 == [0,2,4,6,8,10,8,6,4,2,0]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[x-2 .. 0]` will be empty, since there is no "*then*" item, it will make steps of one. You can make such list with `[x-2, x-4 .. 0]`. You can implement the `mountain` function with:

```
mountain :: Int -> [Int]
mountain i = [0, 2 .. n] ++ [n-2, n-4 .. 0]
    where n = 2 * div i 2
```

Comment: Or `mountain i = l ++ tail (reverse l) where l = [0, 2 .. n]`. The list comprehension already has the behaviour of rounding down-to-even.